# Convert JSON response body in node JS

Tags: node.js, json, express

I have recently started working on Node JS and very new to it. I am querying the db to get the results based on the d_num (there could be various rows for one d_num). I get the result in below JSON format -

```
[
    {
        "PRIMARY_ID": 1,
        "D_NUM": "090703",
        "START_DATE": "2021-06-01",
        "END_DATE": "2022-05-31",
        "F_NUM": 1.049,
        "LAST_MODIFIED": "2021-06-02 05:34:04.382279"
    },
{
        "PRIMARY_ID": 2,
        "D_NUM": "090703",
        "START_DATE": "2020-08-01",
        "END_DATE": "2021-05-31",
        "F_NUM": 0.998,
        "LAST_MODIFIED": "2020-06-02 08:34:04.382279"
    }
]
```

I want to change the above JSON format in the below format -

```
[
    {
        "dnum": "090703",
        "details" :[{
            "primaryid":"1",
            "startdate": "2021-06-01",
            "enddate": "2022-05-31",
            "fnum": 1.049,
            "lastmodifieddate": "2021-06-02 05:34:04.382279"
        },
         {
            "primaryid":"2",
            "startdate": "2020-08-01",
            "enddate": "2021-05-31",
            "fnum": 0.998,
            "lastmodifieddate": "2020-06-02 08:34:04.382279"
        }]
    }
]
```

Below is my code -

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

router.get('/:id', async (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.id;
    const getDetails = await executeDb2Query({
        sql: SQL_QUERIES.GET_DETAILS,
        values: [id],
        log: req.log,
        name: 'Get Details',
        errorMsg: 'Get error while getting Details '
    })
    return res.json(getDetails);
})
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

```
const data= [
    {
        "PRIMARY_ID": 1,
        "D_NUM": "090703",
        "START_DATE": "2021-06-01",
        "END_DATE": "2022-05-31",
        "F_NUM": 1.049,
        "LAST_MODIFIED": "2021-06-02 05:34:04.382279"
    },
    {
        "PRIMARY_ID": 2,
        "D_NUM": "090703",
        "START_DATE": "2020-08-01",
        "END_DATE": "2021-05-31",
        "F_NUM": 0.998,
        "LAST_MODIFIED": "2020-06-02 08:34:04.382279"
    }
]

function convertItem(item) {
    const newItem = {}
    Object.keys(item).filter(key => key !== 'D_NUM').forEach(key => { newItem[key.toLowerCase().replace('_', '')] = item[key] })
    return newItem
}

const newData = { dnum: data[0]['D_NUM'], details: data.map(convertItem)}
console.log(newData)
```